# Adding <span> tags around each primary item in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I'd like my primary links in Drupal to look like this in code:

```
<a class="active" title="Go to the Foo Homepage" href="/"><span>Home</span></a>
```

Rather than:

```
<a class="active" title="Go to the Foo Homepage" href="/">Home</a>
```

So I can then style the `span` separately from the `a`.

(I know that sounds like a slightly strange thing to do, but it's to do with working around IE's lack of border-radius support coupled with the inability to set 2 background images.)

So do you know where & how I get Drupal to insert these tags in all my primary links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing, somewhere in your `page.tpl.php`, you have something like this to display the primary menu :

```
print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'links primary-links'));
```

One solution *(might not be the cleanest one -- but should work)* would be to iterate on the elements of `$primary_links`, to, for each one, :

- activate HTML mode
- wrap the `title` with `<span>` and `</span>`

If your menu has only one level, I suppose this would do :

```
foreach ($primary_links as & $link) {
  $link['html'] = true;
  $link['title'] = '<span>' . $link['title'] . '</span>';
}
```

And, after that, you can call `theme` like you're already doing now.

With that, you should get `<span>` tags arround the text of the link, without having them injected in the `title`'s attribute of the `<a>` tags.

I you have more levels in your menu, you will have to iterate farther down ; either with two imbricated loops, or with some kind of recursion if you don't know the depth of your menus.

(I'll let you have fun with that ; what I said should be enough to get you started ;-) )

As a sidenote, this could probably done somewhere in `template.php` too... Might be a better place ; but I'll let you decide which solution you prefer...

Have fun !

Comment: That was REALLY close - thanks for pointing me in the right direction. In the end I had to edit `$primary_links_tree` though as my theme was using that to make the menu rather than just `$primary_links`. Close enough to be accepted as the answer I reckon :)

Comment: You're welcome :-) OK about the variable's name : I took the one from the garland default theme, and didn't think about saying it might require some tunning ^^

Comment: Actually that's proving a LOT harder than I expected since `$primary_links_tree` is pre-rendered by the time it's called in `page.tpl.php` and I can't seem to trace it back far enough to get it to insert like you said there...

Comment: Too bad about $primary_links_tree :-(

Answer (score 0):

This should help http://drupal.org/node/221382

Scroll down to this comment for the final solution http://drupal.org/node/221382#comment-755469. There are issues with the html output which are resolved there.

Comment: Thanks, but again, this is in relation to `$primary_links` not `$primary_links_tree` which is ouput as a `ul` and comes from a completely different place.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, in the end I just used the [menu_html module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_html) and entered the menu items as `<span>Menu Item 1</span>` in the relevant dialogues.

In fact I ended up with `<span><span>Menu Item Expanded</span></span>` in one of them because it was expanded and already had a background image set. It now has 3!

At least my curved corners on my tabs are working now in IE. Another time that IE soaks up 5/6 hours just because it doesn't support CSS properly!